# How to register custom UserStore & UserManager in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

Here is my setup:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
}
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
}
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>
{
}
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>
{
}
public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>
{
}
```

Here is the definition of my UserStore

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, MyContext, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of my UserManager

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IEnumerable<IUserTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>> tokenProviders,
        ILoggerFactory logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
        : base(
            store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors,
            tokenProviders, logger, contextAccessor)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the definition of my DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And here is my Startup.cs

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:DbConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext, Guid>()
            .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Populate(services);
        var container = builder.Build();
        return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

The dependency of this constructor will work:

```
public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
```

This one won't:

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
```

Anyone has an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which nuget package version did you reference for Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core? I am trying to create a CustomUsermanager, but when I inherit from UserManager the constructor asks for 9 parameters, but your constructor takes 10 arguments..?
I am using the AspDotNetCoreFullFramework.

Comment: `IUserTokenProvider` is not recognized!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

DI in general is intended for interface-driven development; `.AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()` specifies an implementation `UserManager<>`, not the service interface. That means that it's still expecting you to get `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and only use it that way; it'll give you an `ApplicationUserManager`.

I'm assuming that you have additional methods you want to use on your `ApplicationUserManager`. **If not,** *just use the dependency constructor the way it works and enjoy the interface-driven development.* If so, you have 3 options:

1. **Use extension via composition rather than inheritance.** Rather than inheriting from `UserManager<>`, write `ApplicationUserManager` as a wrapper class; you can include it in the constructor. This should give you all the functionality you need inside of the `ApplicationUserManager`.
2. **Add it as-is to the DI framework yourself.** This isn't as difficult as it sounds, since the `UserManager<>` has no real state itself:

   ```
   services.AddScoped<ApplicationUserManager>();
   ```

   The disadvantage here is that you'll actually have two `UserManager<>` objects for the user's scope; there could be some inefficiencies as a result. From the state of the current code, I don't think it is.
3. **Write it as extension methods.** If you have a number of dependencies and not just the `UserManager<>`'s base functionality, this could be really complex.

Comment: Exactly right, I'm actually going to fix this 'soonish' https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/493

Answer (score 5):

I am now on ASP.NET Core 1.1 and this behavior has been fixed.

I can easily implement my own UserManager and UserStore, then bootstrap the app as following:

```
// identity models
services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext, Guid>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

and inject both UserManager and UserStore into my Controller, without any problem:

```
public AccountController(
    IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
    IClientStore clientStore,
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    ApplicationUserManager userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    IEmailSender emailSender,
    ISmsSender smsSender,
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _interaction = interaction;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _emailSender = emailSender;
    _smsSender = smsSender;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AccountController>();
    _account = new AccountService(_interaction, httpContextAccessor, clientStore);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - let me in the right direction! Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
// Extract IApplicationUserManager interface with all methods you are using
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationUserManager

// Register your custom user manager
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

// Return same scoped instance whenever you injecting your custom user manager into any constructor
services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserManager>(s => s.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
```