# .NET Core Web API An exception was thrown while activating

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm getting the following exception when sending a post request to my web api:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown
>   while activating WAM4.WebAPI.Core.UseCases.RegisterUserUseCase ->
>   WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Data.Repositories.UserRepository ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser,
>   WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]. --->
>   Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors
>   found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser]'
>   can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>       Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser]
>   store' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser],
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordHasher`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserValidator`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser]],
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IPasswordValidator`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser]],
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ILookupNormalizer,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityErrorDescriber,
>   System.IServiceProvider,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser]])'.

These are my 2 modules that get "build()" into the container and the AppUser class:

```
    public class InfrastructureModule : Module
        {
            protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
                builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
                builder.RegisterType<JwtFactory>().As<IJwtFactory>().SingleInstance().FindConstructorsWith(new InternalConstructorFinder());
                builder.RegisterType<JwtTokenHandler>().As<IJwtTokenHandler>().SingleInstance().FindConstructorsWith(new InternalConstructorFinder());
                builder.RegisterType<TokenFactory>().As<ITokenFactory>().SingleInstance();
                builder.RegisterType<JwtTokenValidator>().As<IJwtTokenValidator>().SingleInstance().FindConstructorsWith(new InternalConstructorFinder());
                builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
            }
        }


public class CoreModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<RegisterUserUseCase>().As<IRegisterUserUseCase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<LoginUseCase>().As<ILoginUseCase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            builder.RegisterType<ExchangeRefreshTokenUseCase>().As<IExchangeRefreshTokenUseCase>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//using System;
//using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //Add additional profile data for application users by adding properties to this class
        //[Required]
        //[MaxLength(100)]
        //public string FirstName { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //[MaxLength(100)]
        //public string LastName { get; set; }

        ////[Required]
        ////public byte SecurityLevel { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        //public int Pending { get; set; }

        //public string Avatar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've checked to see that UserRepository is properly registered in Load, and that AppUser class is properly compiled. Any guidance on what area I should be looking into to resolve this exception, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To improve your chance in getting high-quality answers, make sure your question contains a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what I was doing wrong.

I omitted the JWTToken code from the template Startup.cs, because I hadn't gotten to that part yet. Big Mistake, spent the whole day thinking it was a different issue...Made my startup.cs the same as the template I was following (including all the JWT and Authentication code)...and BAM, easy fix. only took a whole 8 hours to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Thank you llya for trying to help, appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard without your registration to tell exactly, but it looks like you are missing registration of `IUserStore` in your container. Can you verify that it is registered, by e.g. doing resolve after all the registrations are performed?

Since it's a generic interface `IUserStore<TUser>`, is it possible that you don't register a correct generic version with `WAM4.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Identity.AppUser`

Comment: I dont see AppUser registering IUserStore. It does however implement IdentityUser. I'm following a template I found online, which compiles and works fine on my computer. That template doesn't explicitly register IUserStore either...

Comment: How do you get an error if it works fine you your computer? Not sure I understand you. If you have IUserStore<AppUser> parameter in your constructor you have to register it, it won't be registered on it's own. DI container can't inject what is not registered

Comment: I have a source code example that i downloaded from github, that one works. I followed the tutorial for it and tried to duplicate it from scratch, which is the one that is not working. I will try and register IUserStore...the source code i'm following is at this link, in case anyone wants to know: https://fullstackmark.com/post/19/jwt-authentication-flow-with-refresh-tokens-in-aspnet-core-web-api

Comment: help on what class Registertype I should use? denoted by .....            
builder.RegisterType<....>.As<IUserStore<AppUser>>.InstancePerLifeTimeScope();

Comment: I cannot unfortunately tell you what is that exactly you need to register as I am not aware 100% of the details of working with these classes. It is possible that it can be registered not directly but indirectly via some `AddUserStore` extension method. Since you use your own class I assume you should read on how to implement a custom store and connect it to the DI in documentation. There is some info I found here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453567/how-to-register-custom-userstore-usermanager-in-di/30457561. Perhaps you need to implement some custom user store and register it